# All XHR request in electron 7.0.0-beta.5 are getting cancelled?

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder

This only happens in the production build version V7.0.0-beta.5, not in development.

1: create a new Vue app:

```
vue create test-app
```

2: add electron builder

```
vue add electron-builder
```

3: By default it will have version

```
"electron": "^6.0.0"
```

change it to

`"electron": "^7.0.0-beta.5"` inside package.json

4: delete (previously installed) node modules (Without this step it normally fails to update electron version)

5: install node modules

```
npm install
```

6: build the app for production

```
npm run electron:build
```

7: run the app go to the network tab, all the requests will be getting cancelled

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Expected behavior
It should not cancel the requests, either it should give success or error code

Environment:
OS and version: Windows 10
node version: V10.16.3
npm version: V6.9.0
electron version: ^7.0.0-beta.5

It is working fine if we rollback to V6.0.0, but my application functionality is dependent on electron V7.0.0-beta.5 ( Electron print functionality fix )

Comment: Sounds like an issue with electron v7. Have you considered checking their issues list? I'm not entirely sure what sort of response you're after here

Comment: I see you have raised an issue. You should probably wait for a response there

Comment: This issue got fixed in the next release of electron.